# Push into array if the date right now is in between two other dates

Tags: php, date

When the user visits a product/service page, I do a check to see whether or not there is an offer available if the current date falls on or between two other dates.

The method I am using doesn't seem practical and probably wont scale too well, but it does seems to work... What do you think?

```
$right_now = strtotime('2000-'.date('m').'-'.date('d'));
$offers = [];

switch ($page_name) {
    case 'page1':
        if ($right_now >= strtotime('2000-06-25') && $right_now <= strtotime('2000-09-01')) { #June 25 - September 1
            $offers[] = 'test1';
        }
    break;
    case 'page2':
        if ($right_now >= strtotime('2000-08-01') && $right_now <= strtotime('2000-10-31')) { #August 1 - October 31
            $offers[] = 'test2';
        }
    break;
    default:
        $offers = null;
    break;
}

#Create list of offers available for this page
if (!empty($offers[0])) {
    ?><ul id="offer"><?php
    foreach ($offers as $ofs) {
        ?><li><?php echo $ofs; ?></li><?php
    }
    ?></ul><?php
}
```

UPDATE: I only care about the month and day, the year is not important.

Comment: A project like this SHOULD use a database. Your offers should be in a database. Then, the optimization you want should be in the query to get the offers, such as: `select * from offers where startdate<=CURDATE() and enddate>=CURDATE();`

Comment: I may only have around 5 offers to check for; i'm trying to get away with not relying on a database if I can help it (for now).

Comment: Append 23:59:59 to end date, eg.: '2000-09-01 23:59:59'. Otherwise you'll get 09-01 or 10-31 not in range problem.